# usb device (usbtiny) avrdude not found

Tags: usb

I moved recently on ubuntu since i had probelm with windows drivers, but i am having some issues here too

ubuntu 16.04

dmesg output:

```
    [ 3625.555366] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 3625.699443] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1781, idProduct=0c9f
[ 3625.699449] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3625.699452] usb 3-1: Product: USBtinyISP
```

avrdude output:

```
avrdude: Version 6.2
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/vincenzo/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : usbtiny
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found USBtinyISP, bus:device: 003:007
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : USBtiny
         Description     : USBtiny simple USB programmer, http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/
avrdude: programmer operation not supported

avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

someone would like to give me some help?
I don't think it is a problem of permission but i could be wrong

Comment: It looks like it's finding the device and the system wide configuration file fine. What is your question?

Comment: I'm not able to use it anyway, but i am sure it should works: initialization failed, rc=-1

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand. You might find this useful https://learn.adafruit.com/usbtinyisp

Comment: i thought it wasn't working since that "initialization failed" but i tested it and you are right everything is fine

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted.